# How to convert datetime value into integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a string which resulted from a datetime difference operation:

```
a=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp1'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
b=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp2'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

df['timestamp3'] = b-a

OUT 
19 days 06:45:43
```

Now I need to convert it into the integer 19. How can this be done?
Thanks!

Comment: could you share your code on how did you generate that time?

Comment: Do you want just the number of days '19' as a result ?

Comment: @JannAnthonyBriza yes, sorry i just added it.

Comment: @SundeepPidugu yes just 19 as a number

Comment: `(b-a).dt.days`?

Comment: have you tried `b-a.dt.day`?

Comment: @QuangHoang it worked!!! thanks